# Can someone please explain this recursion question the problem is solved?

Tags: java, recursion

> Given base and n that are both 1 or more, compute recursively (no
>   loops) the value of base to the n power, so powerN(3, 2) is 9 (3
>   squared).

The answer is

```
public int powerN(int base, int n) {

if(n == 1)
        return base;
    return base * powerN(base, n - 1);
}
```

I am confused because when I look at this because is this not saying multiply the base against the returned number of `powerN()`?

> powerN(3,3);
>
> = 3
>
> = 3*powerN(base, n-1) = 6
>
> = 3*powerN(base, n-1) = 9

Which would multiply 9*6*3?

I do not see why we would have to multiply the base by the function?

Should the method not just return the answer as the base never changes and once `n==1` the base case executes

Comment: `powernN(2, 4) = 2 * powerN(2, 3) = 2 * 2 * powerN(2, 2) = 2 * 2 * 2 * powerN(2,1) = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2 * 2 * 4 = 2 * 8 = 16`

Comment: Take a pen and paper, and write out what the values for each variable is, starting at `base=3` and `n=3`, for the _entire_ run. You start on 3,3 then  n==1 fails, so instead you return 3 * powerN(3, 3-1), so now you're in powerN(3,2), now what happens? and simply by writing that out, you've answered your own question.

Comment: Why is `3*powerN(base, n-1) = 6`? If `powerN(3,3) = 3 * powerN(3,3-1)` then the next step *also* yields `3`. So, you calculate `3*3*3` in the end.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you don't understand recursion, did you try to run the code in the debugger. It's a very helpful tool to understand how code executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have `powerN(2,3)`

```
powerN(2,3):

call#1> return 2*powerN(2,3-1)
call#2> return 2*powerN(2,2-1)
call#3> (n==1)return 2*1
```

So,

```
call#3 returns 2 to call#2 [call#2 is now returning 2*2=4]
call#2 returns 4 to call#1 [call#1 is now returning 2*4=8]
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate powerN(3,3) as you did.

1. `powerN(3,3) = 3 * powerN(3,2)`
2. `3 * powerN(3,2) = 3 * 3 * powerN(3,1)`
3. `3 * 3 * powerN(3,1) = 3 * 3 * 3 = 27`

So it was just wrong the way you calculated.